# How can I simulate Tab Key and Enter Key press, using JavaScript for TruClient

Tags: javascript, tabs, truclient

I am working on LR Truclient, which uses JavaScript as underlying language. I have a scenario, where I need to click 'Tab' key and then 'Enter' key (to change the focus to browser pop button, which I am not able to handle with default steps available in Truclient), where I have to write the code in JavaScript to achieve the same. Can some one help with a piece of code in JS, to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to send the "tab" using the built-in steps?  You need to add a "Generic Object Action" and then configure as follows:

Define the generic action as a key press:
[Step: Press Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVVDz.png)

Configure the key press to be a tab:
[Argument: Tab key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lag9S.png)

You might need to "press" tab several times to land in the correct button. You can use the same technique to press "Enter".